# A sentence with preposition at the end of sentence and without it

Tags: grammar

I'm confused that some sentence have the preposition at the end of sentence.

What is the difference between

",that you can think of" and ",that you can think"?

the former sentence is that I came across it from subtitle of community, but last sentence is what I just thought it.

I want to know when I have such as that sentence, how do I know some sentence in need of preposition at the end of sentence or not?

Comment: Neither of your examples are full sentences.

Comment: Are you talking about the *location* of a preposition (at the end or earlier), or its presence or complete absence (in any location)? There is a big difference. You haven't provided complete sentences, and what you're actually asking is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either could be correct, depending on the intended meaning.

> That is the noblest thought that you can think.

This describes the thought itself.

> It was the noblest action that I could think of.

This describes the action, not the thought.

> It was the only solution that I could think of.
>
> That he had betrayed me was the only thing that I could think.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is ". . . that you can think of." It is perfectly okay to end your sentence with a preposition if it is part of a verb-preposition combo, which there are many (e.g. *look at, talk about, depend on, etc.)*.

There's no other way around than just learning the common verb-preposition combinations. See the attached list for common combinations.

[image]